# Erro ao compilar aplicativo Ionic com Crosswalk

Tags: android, ionic, apache-cordova, cordova-plugin, crosswalk

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que terá suporte para Android 4.1+ e estou 
tendo problemas ao compilar o APK para dispositivos Android 4.4<.

Na documentação do Ionic há algumas informações a respeito da sua 
compatibilidade com versões antigas e lá diz que podemos dar suporte até a 
versão 4.1 se utilizarmos o plugin Crosswalk do Cordova.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/overview/#browser-support

> Obs: não encontrei na documentação onde diz o suporte do Ionic 3

Porém, quando adiciono o plugin Crosswalk, conforme recomendação, meu aplicativo
não compila.

[image: Erro ao compilar com crosswalk]

> Obs: sem o plugin Crosswalk compila normalmente

[image: Compilação sem crosswalk]

### Abaixo estão listadas as etapas que foram percorridas até acontecer o erro de compilação

Eu iniciei um novo aplicativo com o template blank chamado crosswalk-test

**ionic start crosswalk-test blank**

Adicionei a plataforma android

**ionic cordova platform add android**

Compilei o aplicativo normalmente, sem nenhum erro.

**ionic cordova build android**

```
adrianoazevedo at MacBook-Pro-de-Adriano in ~/sites/testes/crosswalk-test on master*
$ ionic cordova build android
Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova
[10:28:42]  build dev started ...
[10:28:42]  clean started ...
[10:28:42]  clean finished in 1 ms
[10:28:42]  copy started ...
[10:28:42]  deeplinks started ...
[10:28:42]  deeplinks finished in 13 ms
[10:28:42]  transpile started ...
[10:28:44]  transpile finished in 2.77 s
[10:28:44]  preprocess started ...
[10:28:44]  preprocess finished in less than 1 ms
[10:28:44]  webpack started ...
[10:28:45]  copy finished in 2.90 s
[10:28:50]  webpack finished in 5.25 s
[10:28:50]  sass started ...
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[10:28:51]  sass finished in 1.12 s
[10:28:51]  postprocess started ...
[10:28:51]  postprocess finished in 6 ms
[10:28:51]  lint started ...
[10:28:51]  build dev finished in 9.28 s
> cordova build android
Android Studio project detected

ANDROID_HOME=/Users/adrianoazevedo/Library/Android/sdk/
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home
studio
> Task :wrapper


BUILD SUCCESSFUL
 in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
[10:28:53]  lint finished in 2.42 s
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.

The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
  at build_ab9wpoe0dxzohv490hhzy0b6g.run(/Users/adrianoazevedo/Sites/testes/crosswalk-test/platforms/android/app/build.gradle:143)
:CordovaLib:preBuild
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl

:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript

:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest

:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig

:CordovaLib:prepareLintJar

:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues

:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources

:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources

:CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor

:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest

:CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug

:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes
 NO-SOURCE
:app:preBuild
 UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild

:app:compileDebugAidl

:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript
 NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript

:app:checkDebugManifest

:app:generateDebugBuildConfig

:app:prepareLintJar

:app:generateDebugResValues

:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources

:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests

:app:processDebugManifest

:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug

:app:compileDebugNdk
 NO-SOURCE

:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders

:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders

:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets

:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets

:app:mergeDebugShaders

:app:compileDebugShaders

:app:generateDebugAssets

:app:mergeDebugAssets

:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders

:CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug

:CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForDebug

:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders

:app:processDebugJavaRes
NO-SOURCE
:app:validateSigningDebug
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources

:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug

:app:processDebugResources

:app:generateDebugSources
:app:javaPreCompileDebug

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:app:compileDebugSources
:app:transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForDebug

:app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug

:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug

:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug
:app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug

:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug

:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug

:app:packageDebug

:app:assembleDebug
:app:cdvBuildDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
46 actionable tasks: 46 executed

Built the following apk(s):
  /Users/adrianoazevedo/sites/testes/crosswalk-test/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
```

Então adicionei o plugin Crosswalk

**ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview**

E tentei compilar novamente, porém dessa vez sem sucesso.

**ionic cordova build android**

```
adrianoazevedo at MacBook-Pro-de-Adriano in ~/sites/testes/crosswalk-test on master*
$ ionic cordova build android
Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova
[10:33:17]  build dev started ...
[10:33:17]  clean started ...
[10:33:18]  clean finished in 2 ms
[10:33:18]  copy started ...
[10:33:18]  deeplinks started ...
[10:33:18]  deeplinks finished in 17 ms
[10:33:18]  transpile started ...
[10:33:20]  transpile finished in 2.71 s
[10:33:20]  preprocess started ...
[10:33:20]  preprocess finished in less than 1 ms
[10:33:20]  webpack started ...
[10:33:20]  copy finished in 2.85 s
[10:33:25]  webpack finished in 5.21 s
[10:33:25]  sass started ...
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[10:33:27]  sass finished in 1.04 s
[10:33:27]  postprocess started ...
[10:33:27]  postprocess finished in 6 ms
[10:33:27]  lint started ...
[10:33:27]  build dev finished in 9.12 s
> cordova build android
Android Studio project detected

ANDROID_HOME=/Users/adrianoazevedo/Library/Android/sdk/
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.

[10:33:29]  lint finished in 2.44 s
null
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
  at build_ab9wpoe0dxzohv490hhzy0b6g.run(/Users/adrianoazevedo/Sites/testes/crosswalk-test/platforms/android/app/build.gradle:144)
org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23+

Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
:CordovaLib:preBuild
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:prepareLintJar
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes
 NO-SOURCE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug

UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild
 UP-TO-DATE
:app:preArm64DebugBuild

:app:compileArm64DebugAidl

:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript

NO-SOURCE
:app:compileArm64DebugRenderscript

:app:checkArm64DebugManifest
:app:generateArm64DebugBuildConfig

:app:prepareLintJar

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets
UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE

:app:mergeArm64DebugShaders

:app:compileArm64DebugShaders

:app:generateArm64DebugAssets

:app:mergeArm64DebugAssets

:app:createXwalkCommandLineFileArm64Debug

:app:generateArm64DebugResValues
:app:generateArm64DebugResources
:app:mergeArm64DebugResources

:app:createArm64DebugCompatibleScreenManifests

:app:processArm64DebugManifest

:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskArm64Debug

:app:processArm64DebugResources
/Users/adrianoazevedo/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/xwalk_core_library-23.53.589.4.aar/5fecbab6d6cf62a172c339a6375bb89d/res/values/dimens_03.xml:14:5-51: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.


/Users/adrianoazevedo/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/xwalk_core_library-23.53.589.4.aar/5fecbab6d6cf62a172c339a6375bb89d/res/values/dimens_03.xml:14:5-51: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

/Users/adrianoazevedo/Sites/testes/crosswalk-test/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeArm64DebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:99: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
/Users/adrianoazevedo/Sites/testes/crosswalk-test/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeArm64DebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:99: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Failed to execute aapt

com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

  at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)

  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)

  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)

  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)

  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)

  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)

  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)

  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)

  at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
  ... 47 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
  at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
  at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:454)
  at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:411)
  at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
  at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 FAILED
* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:processArm64DebugResources'.

>
Failed to execute aapt

* Try:

Run with
--stacktrace
 option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
 option to get more log output.


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED
 in 3s
32 actionable tasks: 15 executed, 17 up-to-date
(node:9820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /Users/adrianoazevedo/sites/testes/crosswalk-test/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/Users/adrianoazevedo/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/xwalk_core_library-23.53.589.4.aar/5fecbab6d6cf62a172c339a6375bb89d/res/values/dimens_03.xml:14:5-51: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

/Users/adrianoazevedo/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/xwalk_core_library-23.53.589.4.aar/5fecbab6d6cf62a172c339a6375bb89d/res/values/dimens_03.xml:14:5-51: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

/Users/adrianoazevedo/Sites/testes/crosswalk-test/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeArm64DebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:99: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
/Users/adrianoazevedo/Sites/testes/crosswalk-test/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeArm64DebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:99: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
  at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor202.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
  at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
  ... 47 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
  at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
  at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:454)
  at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:411)
  at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
  at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOu
tput.java:104)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processArm64DebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/adrianoazevedo/sites/testes/crosswalk-test/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:936:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
(node:9820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9820) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

### ionic info

```
adrianoazevedo at MacBook-Pro-de-Adriano in ~/sites/testes/crosswalk-test on master*
$ ionic info

cli packages: (/Users/adrianoazevedo/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v9.11.1
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : macOS High Sierra

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : /Users/adrianoazevedo/Library/Android/sdk/

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Comment: veja o link abaixo onde há orientações para editar o plugin.xml [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727543/cordova-8-0-0-build-failed-after-add-crosswalk-plugin][1]

Comment: @JoseIramAbreudeSouza, vou testar. Assim que eu tiver um retorno comento aqui. Valeu!